# Как задать image бэкграундом у StatusBar UWP?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

Видел такое в приложениях в магазине. Не просто залитый одним цветом статус бар, а картинка, которая начинается ещё в приложении, и занимает область стаус бара как бг. Или же это просто скрытый статус бар, и свои часы? Скриншот приложения Вконтакте, из Магазина:[image: Скриншот приложения Вконтакте, из Магазина]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть такой вариант реализации:
Сдвигаете свой контент на высоту статус бара (Margin c минусом по высоте)
далее отрабатываете логику по поведению вашего ScrollViewer'a

```
internallScrollViewer.ViewChanging += OnScrollViewerViewChanging;
```

в событие описываете движение

```
    protected virtual void OnScrollViewerViewChanging(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        var vertialOffset = e.NextView.VerticalOffset;
        var viewAreaHeight = ImageHeight - _statusBar.OccludedRect.Height;
        var newValue = vertialOffset / viewAreaHeight;
        AnimateOverlayBorderSlice(_previousValue, newValue);
        _previousValue = newValue;
        _imageTransform.TranslateY = Math.Max(vertialOffset * (-0.25), -1 * viewAreaHeight);
    }
```

и красиво анимируете свой Border Overlay

```
    private void AnimateOverlayBorderSlice(double from, double to, double miliseconds = 350)
    {
        var storyboard = new Storyboard();
        var doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        doubleAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(miliseconds);
        doubleAnimation.EnableDependentAnimation = true;
        doubleAnimation.From = from;
        doubleAnimation.To = to;
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation, "Opacity");
        Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnimation, _imageOverlayBorder);
        storyboard.Children.Add(doubleAnimation);
        storyboard.Begin();
    }
```

Сам стиль контрола выглядит немного некрасиво, но не было времени придумать более интересное решение

```
<Style TargetType="specificControls:ParallaxNewsViewer">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="specificControls:ParallaxNewsViewer">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid x:Name="ImageContainer"
                          Margin="0,-28,0,0"
                          Height="300"
                          VerticalAlignment="Top"
                          CacheMode="BitmapCache"
                          RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <Grid.RenderTransform>
                            <CompositeTransform x:Name="ImageTransform" />
                        </Grid.RenderTransform>

                        <Image Source="{Binding ImageAddress, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                               RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                               Stretch="UniformToFill"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

                        <Border Background="{StaticResource GreenBrush}"
                                Opacity="0"
                                x:Name="ImageOverlay"/>

                    </Grid>

                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentScrollViewer">
                        <ScrollViewer.Content>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid Height="200"/>

                                <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1"
                                                  Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                                  ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollViewer.Content>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Вы снова меня спасаете уважаемый @Andrii Krupka!